# Spring boot + Jackson. How to serialize collections which have null value as empty lists?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

In my entity I have:

```
private Set<Account> accounts;
```

Now it is being serialized like this:

```
"accounts": null
```

I need to change it to

```
"accounts": []
```

I have many (150+) entities which have this problem - how can configure jackson mapper to achieve this?

Comment: use empty collection instead of null

Comment: Yes, that will definitely help but I can't do this do to reasons which I can't change unfortunately.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432133/jackson-serialize-non-initialized-collection-field-as-empty

Comment: In your entity, is the account a list ?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I'm aware about this. But I have about 150+ entity classes so writing JsonSerializer implementation for each will be not best solution inmy case.

Comment: @yashpandey I updated question. Entity has set of accounts.

Comment: There does not appear to be a setting in Jackson for this, so you're either going to have to use empty collections or write a serializer.  Using a serializer may be possible if your entity classes can inherit from a single parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think declaring your set like this will work...

```
private Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<>();
```

It's then an empty set when marshalling and not null.

Comment: This is what we do where I currently work.  Much easier, and we just avoid passing null to the setter for the variable.

Comment: That should work. It can also be done in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the "accounts" completely from the json annotating your pojo with:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

maybe this helps

Comment: I need to keep accounts in my json, need to have it as [] if it is null.