# Jackson null list to empty array serialization

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I want to serialize null List to empty array.

So given:

```
class MyBean { List values; }
```

And given an instance with null for values, it should be serialized to:

```
{ "values": [] }
```

I want this to be global behaviour for all Lists in all classes. I do not want to add any annotations or specific handling for classes.

I have read all related questions I found, and could not come up with anything that works. Seems any custom serializer I try to register for List class is not kicking in.

If you have this working on your project, let me know how did you manage to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases like this you need to customize `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` class. Te serialize `null`-s, by default, `Jackson` uses `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NullSerializer` class. You can extend default introspector class and override `findNullSerializer`.

See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.Annotated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new EmptyArrayJacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
        mapper.writeValue(System.out, new ListWrapper());
    }
}

class EmptyArrayJacksonAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

    @Override
    public Object findNullSerializer(Annotated a) {
        if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(a.getRawType())) {
            return ArrayNullSerializer.INSTANCE;
        }
        return super.findNullSerializer(a);
    }
}

final class ArrayNullSerializer extends StdSerializer<Object> {

    public static final ArrayNullSerializer INSTANCE = new ArrayNullSerializer();

    protected ArrayNullSerializer() {
        super(Object.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartArray();
        gen.writeEndArray();
    }
}

class ListWrapper {

    private List values;

    public List getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"values":[]}
```

Comment: Worked on the first try! Thanks! I Should probably link this answer to other related questions that did not help me forward.

Comment: @Raipe, I'm glad to hear that. If you think it would be helpful for others you can add my answer in comments to other questions you found at the beginning.

Comment: if you have any additional information on why this is the solution to use, I would be happy to learn. Doing this through annotation inspectors sounds really strange (works though).

Comment: @Raipe, There is nothing strange with this solution. You can define `NullSerialiser` using `@JsonSerialise` annotation but you explicitly wrote, you do not want to do that. So, we can trick `Jackson` and force it to always use our custom implementation for `List` type. `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` is a class which reads annotations and configures a way how given object is serialized or deserialized.